# Jquery image alt on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one question about image alt on hover image.

I have to create this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ev82vbou/2/)**

In this fiddle you can see there are big and smole images. When you hoverover smole image then big image changing.

What i want to do. I want to add a `alt` from big image. In my demo shows `alt` with only smole images. Also my code said undefined. What i need to do for showing alt only from big images.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = $(this).attr('alt');
    $("#magazin_sldwr li img").hover(function(){
        clearTimeout(autoScrollerTimer);
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        $('#mainm-img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', '')).parent().attr('href',$(this).parent().attr('href'),$(this).parent().append('<div class="title">' + a + '</div>'));

    }, function(){
        autoChangeImage();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `undefined` problem:
You're setting the variable `a` to `$(this).attr('alt')` too early, before `$(this)` is the thumbnail.

Try setting it in the function you pass to `hover()`, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var a;
    $("#magazin_sldwr li img").hover(function(){
        a = $(this).attr('alt');
        clearTimeout(autoScrollerTimer);
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        $('#mainm-img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', '')).parent().attr('href',$(this).parent().attr('href'),$(this).parent().append('<div class="title">' + a + '</div>'));

    }, function(){
        autoChangeImage();
});
```

For showing the other alt text, you'll have to be more detailed in your question.

Comment: @be-fehr thanks for your answer. But it shows me `alt` with smole image. I want to show `alt` with big image. How can i do this ?

Comment: The big image has alt="", so it's not set. Did you mean that you wanted to fill it with the alt text of the small images?

Comment: @be-fehr  yes i want to fill it with the alt text of small images

Comment: @be-fehr exactly like this thank you. updated your answer i want to give you point :)